# Remove seconds from date time object in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have date time object and it is stored in created datetime. I want to remove the seconds from the datetime object.
My date time object is returning value like this

```
4/6/2016 5:32:00 PM
```

I want to remove the seconds from this and i want the output like below,

```
4/6/2016 5:32 PM
```

can anyone tell how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the value of the DateTime to actually set its seconds to 0, or are you simply trying to get a string for the DateTime that doesn't **show** the seconds?

Answer (score 2):

To get the wanted output, try `yourDateTimeObject.ToString("g");`

Here is some information [DateTime.ToString(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx), which i will recommend for your needs.

Edit:
If you want it to be culture-independent, and always show the same use:
`yourDateTimeObject.ToString("d/M/yyyy h:mm tt");`

Comment: Does this print out also the AM/PM? unable to test from here....

Comment: Yes, it also says on the MSDN link provided. See the last code block on the page :)

Comment: If by print, you mean return a string that can be printed

Comment: Yes, I mean that however if you check on the Standard Format Strings page in the section [`The General Date Short Time ("g") Format Specifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralDateShortTime) there is some doubt about that in the example shown,

Comment: See edit for culture-independent solution